# I can't seem to get the classification for the 2010 LANDSAT

Tags: ndvi, classification

I've been trying to make a script that pulls 2010 and 2020 landsat images, calculate the NDVI from those images, then classify both of them to see the extent of change in vegetation in the area using the subtraction function.

These are the 2 errors I'm getting:
"NDVI 2010: Layer error: Image.normalizedDifference: No band named 'B5'. Available band names: []."
"Change in Mangrove Distribution: Layer error: Image.normalizedDifference: No band named 'B5'. Available band names: []."

I can give the script if needed, just let me know with a response please.

The full code:

```
var collection2010 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')
  .median();

var calculateNDVI = function(image) {
//  var nirBand = image.select('B5');
//  var redBand = image.select('B4');
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var ndvi2010 = calculateNDVI(collection2010);

var visParams2010 = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi2010.select('NDVI'), visParams2010, 'NDVI 2010');

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: trainingData,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: ['NDVI']
});
var classified2010 = ndvi2010.select('NDVI').classify(classifier);

var change = classified2020.subtract(classified2010);

Map.addLayer(change, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'white', 'blue']}, 'Change in Mangrove Distribution');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting Landsat 8 (`LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA`) top of atmosphere data for 2010 - `.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')`. However your filter doesn't return any data as Landsat 8 [wasn't launched until 2013](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-8).

You'll need to use Landsat 5 or 7 for 2010 NDVI.

Note that:

- Landsat 5 & 7 bands 3 & 4 are Red and NIR so use those for [NDVI](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-normalized-difference-vegetation-index#:%7E:text=In%20Landsat%204%2D7%2C%20NDVI,Band%205%20%2B%20Band%204),
- you'll need to be aware of/handle the SLC-off gaps/striping in Landsat 7,
- you should probably use the surface reflectance data instead of TOA (top of atmosphere) for both 2010 and 2020 data, ie.  [LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C02_T1_L2) (Landsat 5) or [LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LE07_C02_T1_L2) (Landsat 7) and [LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2) (Landsat 8)